# When recovering binlogs, should I start the recovery from the beginning time of the dump or the end time of the dump?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

If I restore a mysqldump backup and then I need to recover the other transactions in the binary logs, should I start the recovery from the beginning time of the dump (when the backup has started) or the end time of the dump (when the backup has finished)?

```
mysqlbinlog --start-datetime=?? /backup/mysql-bin.0*
```

I've seen that the last line of the dump has the completed time. Should I use it to start the recovery?

```
...
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2023-12-22 12:24:27
```

But there is no start time on the dump. If I need to recovery from beginning time, how to know the time?

Also, can we recovery only a single database (since binary logs has the change of all databases)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's error-prone to use timestamps because there could be many binlog events in the scale of one second.

The more accurate method is to include the exact binary log coordinates in the dump file. You must use the [`--source-data` option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_source-data) (aka `--master-data` before MySQL 8.0.26) when you create the dump file.

---

Re your comment:

There's no way to get a precise log file and position if the dump was made without the `--source-data` option. You can only guess based on the timestamp, and as I said, this has a strong likelihood of being inaccurate.

You'll either guess too early, and replay changes that were already represented in the dump, or else you'll guess too late, and miss some changes.

The timestamp at the end of the dump file is probably not the one you should use.

If the dump backed up InnoDB tables and the `--single-transaction` option was used, then the dump includes only changes that were committed at the *start* of the dump process, when its transaction was started. But that timestamp is not present in the dump file. The dump outputs a timestamp only at the end. So if you use this timestamp as you read the binary logs, you're bound to miss all the changes that were committed between the start and end of the dump.

If you can get the timestamp when the dump file was created (as opposed to the timestamp of the last write to the dumpfile), you could estimate the timestamp you should start reading from in the binary log. This depends on the operating system whether this information is available.

Comment: Let's say we've just started managing an environment that already has a dump routine in place, but the --source-data option is not used in the dump. Is there any other way to find out the binary log file and position that we need to use? (this situation already happened to me).